# Android Compilation: No rule to make target

Tags: java, android, c++, git, android-kernel

I am trying to compile an android kernel from source for an ODROID-XU4 (http://www.hardkernel.com/main/products/prdt_info.php?g_code=G143452239825). I downloaded the source, added a few custom drivers & external programs, and now I am trying to create a git repo with all kernel source & custom source. Before I created the repo, my source compiled and deployed fine. After creating the repo, pushing my source, and then cloning it back to my machine, the source no longer compiles. Running make at top of the new source results in the following error:

Install: out/target/product/odroidxu3/data/nativetest/dalvik-vm-unit-tests/dalvik-vm-unit-tests

make: *** No rule to make target `out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android_webview_java_intermediates/javalib.jar`, needed by `out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/webviewchromium_intermediates/classes-full-debug.jar`.  Stop.

I believe the problem is with my .gitignore files. I think that pushing to the repo leaves behind some crucial files that are necessary for compilation, but I'm having trouble finding out which files are not included. Any suggestions as to what files might be missing?

For clarification, I have two source trees, one is the original (which compiles successfully) and one which is an exact clone of the original, but is missing files specified by the default .gitignore files.

Also, the android source I downloaded and have been modifying was from here: https://github.com/hardkernel/android.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Delete external folder in your AOSP root directory and replace it with the original one.